# Prevent asserting permissions in sandbox AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, sandbox

I have followed this [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046(v=vs.110).aspx) to create sandbox `AppDomain`.

`PermissionSet` for sandbox `AppDomain`:

```
var permissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
permissions.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
```

Now assume that I'm loading untrusted assembly into sandbox `AppDomain` and create instance of type and execute some method. This method could be anything, could be dangerous.

How can I make shure that this untrusted assembly **can naver** execute following:

```
(new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted)).Assert();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to make sense of this.  The point of sandboxing is to make that code fail.  If you don't trust an assembly and it can only do its job if it runs in full trust then you can't use it.  Simple as that.  Send a bug report to the author.

Comment: AFAIK in .NET Core there's no `AppDomain` anymore, and CAS is also deprecated... I would take my time to decide if I would start a new development relying on `AppDomain` and CAS to implement a sandboxed app...

Comment: See this article to see how Microsoft suggests you should implement that... https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/porting.md#code-access-security-cas

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thanks, any recommendations to go with containers?

Comment: @MatjažMav Really I understand that the new direction in sandboxing should be working with OS security identities and allow or disallow some action based on the account that's impersonating a given application or service...